# How to generate a random number and make sure it is the same for everyone using Photon in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

Hi Guys I am converting a single player Sudoko game into a multiplayer game (right now 2 players) using Photon in Unity.

The basic logic of the Sudoku game is that there are 300 puzzle data already loaded in it. A random number between 1 to 300 is picked up and the corresponding puzzle is loaded.

But the problem I am facing is even though I have made sure that the same number is getting picked up for both the client and the master server, different puzzles are getting loaded.

So basically I script called MultiManager attached to the MultiManager GameObject in the Sudoku screen.The script looks something like this.

```
void Start()
        {          
            PV = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
            
            if (PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
            {
                puzzleIndex = Random.Range(0, 300);
                PV.RPC("RPC_PuzzleIndex", RpcTarget.Others, puzzleIndex);
            }      

            gameManager = FindObjectOfType(typeof(GameManager)) as GameManager;
            gameManager.PlayNewGame("easy");
        }
 [PunRPC]
        void RPC_PuzzleIndex(int puzzleIndexNUmber)
        {
            puzzleIndex = puzzleIndexNUmber;
        }
```

So in the GameManager script you have these functions:

```
public void PlayNewGame(string groupId)
        {
            // Get the PuzzleGroupData for the given groupId
            for (int i = 0; i < puzzleGroups.Count; i++)
            {
                PuzzleGroupData puzzleGroupData = puzzleGroups[i];

                if (groupId == puzzleGroupData.groupId)
                {
                    PlayNewGame(puzzleGroupData);
                    
                    return;
                }
            }

            
        }

private void PlayNewGame(PuzzleGroupData puzzleGroupData)
        {
            // Get a puzzle that has not yet been played by the user
            PuzzleData puzzleData = puzzleGroupData.GetPuzzle();

            // Play the game using the new puzzle data
            PlayGame(puzzleData);
        }
```

And in the PuzzleGroupData class you have this function :

```
public PuzzleData GetPuzzle()
        {
return new PuzzleData(puzzleFiles[MultiManager.puzzleIndex], shiftAmount, groupId);
        }
```

I don't quite get as to whats wrong which is happening. I tried to use other variations like keeping that random number outside of the condition inside of PhotonNetwork.isMasterClient and all, but doesn't work.

If anyone can help it would be great. By the way this Sudoku game was purchased and I am trying to convert it to a mutliPlayer game

Comment: In my case what I've done is that I created the number locally from on-device and sent that number to Photon's event and received that to other device.

Comment: @Ankit isn't that exactly what OP tries to do? The random is generated on the Master and send to the rest of users

Comment: @derHugo and Chethan you are right, my apologies for the rude behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Since the master is usually the first one in a room so also the first one getting `Start` called I think what happens is that your other clients are simply not connected yet when the `RPC` is called.

Further it might also happen (actually pretty likely) that `Start` is called before the RPC has the chance to be received.

I would rather actually wait until you have the value and do

```
void Start()
{          
    PV = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
        
    if (PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
    {
        PV.RPC(name of(RPC_PuzzleIndex), RpcTarget.AllBuffered, Random.Range(0, 300));
    }
}

[PunRPC]
void RPC_PuzzleIndex(int puzzleIndexNUmber)
{
    puzzleIndex = puzzleIndexNUmber;
    gameManager = FindObjectOfType(typeof(GameManager)) as GameManager;
    gameManager.PlayNewGame("easy");
}
```

This way

- the `RpcTarget.AllBuffered` makes sure that also clients joining later will receive the call
- there is no way you start a game without receiving the random value first

Comment: I tried using that, but it doesn't work. The problem I think is as soon as the start method is executed on the master client , the random number over there is generated. But at the same time when the start method is executed on the remote client ,it sees that it is not the master client and the puzzleIndex=0 (which is default value) as I can see for myself repeatedly the same puzzle is getting loaded on the remote client all the time. The remote client is not waiting for the RPC to get called at all

Comment: @ChethanVenkataramaiah see the update at the bottom. I think this way is more appropriate and it can't happen that the game stars before receiving the value ;)

Comment: The updated solutions works perfectly , thanks a lot